# simple-cdd can not auto install local package

Tags: debian, apt

I use simple-cdd to build a custom debian CD. I have an self made deb package ”mypackage_1.0.deb“.
I have added mypackage_1.0.deb into the path specified by "local_package" of the conf file provided to build-simple-cdd. I see mypackage_1.0.deb is successfully copied into the final ISO under pool/main directory. However, if I add "mypackage" into the .packages or .download file used by build-simple-cdd, CD build fails.

I also tried to add "mypackage" into the preseed file and expect the installer would install it. But it causes error during the installation.

What I want is simple, I want to install "mypackage" automatically during the Debian CD installation. All the online guideline only tells how to include local package into the "local_package" directive. Any help is appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

**Any errors in this file `tmp/log/build-debian-cd.log` ?**

If not try to add your package into a folder and do something like this. You can use config file also to mention the local packages.

```
build-simple-cdd  --local-packages /your-local-package-path/
```

use `your-profile-name.packages` file just add the package name.

make sure you added correct package name by checking the package name using `dpkg -I mypackage_1.0.deb | grep Package` and that needs more dependencies better to install that one manually after your custom Debian and check what are the missing dependencies.

Ex your package required `sudo` you need to add `sudo` before in packages file.